# spark-submit scheduling in cron

Tags: unix, apache-spark, cron

I would like to schedule a pyspark script in crontab to run each 5 minutes. I have successfully launched the script manually using this command:

```
spark-submit script.py
```

The problem is that the same command does not seem to work when launched from crontab. The logs don't show anything any details (they are truncated)

```
*/5 * * * * /path/script.sh
```

The file script.sh contains: spark-submit script.py

Please let me know if you have any ideas on how to solve this issue.

Comment: Interesting read: debugging crontab http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info . There might be many different reasons, so check it out

Comment: Thank you for the link! I did some tests and crontab seems to work for executing other commands. The trouble is that for some reasons, it is not "compatible" with spark-submit.

Answer (score 3):

You should put it in a bash file and run this on cron:

Bash File `Your_Script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "RUNNING JOB"
/opt/mapr/spark/spark-1.5.2/bin/spark-submit /Path/To/Your_Script.py parama1
```

So you can easily run it from crantab like this:

```
32 18 * * *  /Path/To/Your_Script.sh
```

Comment: Think to change `/opt/mapr/spark/spark-1.5.2/` by the path to your bin submit.

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problem with you.I solved it by 2 steps:

1. see the cron log: the path of log is /var/spool/mail/${username} in Centos. 
   my log show : cannot find hadoop and $JAVA_HOME
2. `source /etc/profile` : because  $JAVA_HOME and $HADOOP_HOME  configured in /etc/profile in my OS.  If $JAVA_HOME and $HADOOP_HOME configured in ~/.bashrc, should  `source ~/.bashrc`